# wpf datagridcell go in editmodus when focussed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, datagridcell

I have a simple `DataGrid` that has 1 editable column and 1 readonly column.

When I press TAB or ENTER in `editmodus`, the next cell is focused.
But the next cell does not automatically go into `editmodus`.

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGridMain" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionUnit="Cell" SelectionMode="Single">
    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Code">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Description">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Description}" Background="LightGray"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**What is the simplest way to go into `editmodus` upon focusing a cell?**

Comment: what is `editmodus`? Do you mean that a cell gets focused and can be edited?

Comment: Yes. The cell has a display template (CellTemplate) and a edit template (CellEditingTemplate). When you double click, the cell goes into edit modus and the CellEditingTemplate is activated.

Comment: and you want two cells to get a focus and can be edited simultaneously?

Comment: Are you just trying to give your TextBox focus when the cell receives focus and enters CellEditingMode?

Comment: When I am editing a cell, and press tab, the next cell is focussed with a dashed line. Then I have to hit F2 or click again to edit it. I would like the cell to go into editmodus immediatly!

Comment: @ Chris: no, I have found a way to focus the textbox when the cell is in Editmodus. However I need the cell to go into editmodus when it is focussed.

Comment: Ok, ya might stop using the term "editmodus" because it's not a thing, at least not in relation to a wpf datagrid. I agree it's a clever latin sounding term but people won't know what you're talking about at first glance. Anyway have you already tried just tying an EventTrigger to IsFocused to execute the `BeginEditCommand` command? Could be done with `InvokeCommandAction`. Currently the F2 is deliberate to avoid unwanted human error editing of cells so it's an intentional feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up simply subscribing to SelectedCellsChanged event of the datagrid, and calling BeginEdit().

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGridMain" SelectedCellsChanged="GridMainElements_SelectedCellsChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionUnit="Cell" SelectionMode="Single" >
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

And the event:

```
private void GridMainElements_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Selected cells changed");

        if(e != null && e.AddedCells != null && e.AddedCells.Count == 1)
        {
            DataGridCellInfo selectedCell = e.AddedCells[0];

            if(selectedCell.Column == ColumnFormula || selectedCell.Column == ColumnNote)
            {
                GridMainElements.BeginEdit();
            }
        }
    }
```